# Can people who play RotMG on google chrome play with people who play on steam?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I really want to know, because im making a group on steam but i don't know if steam players that don't have Google chrome can also play with the Google chrome players.

Comment: I would strongly assume that the servers are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can play with anyone. It doesn't matter whether you're playing on Browser/Steam/Kongregate/Flash Projector